# Is opening a popup iframe or webpage using slack API supported?

Tags: iframe, slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-dialog

I am working on a slack app and I want it to open a iframe (or webpage) upon entering a slack command so that I can make REST requests and have more flexible styling options compared to what is offered in slack's dialog API.

**Is opening a popup iframe or webpage using slack API supported?**

I couldn't find this anywhere in Slack's API documentation, but I have used Google Drive's slack integration, and their file picker (the popup from the "Add from Google Drive" flow) looks like it presents an iframe/webpage because the styling is much different than the other dialog flows.

I don't want this to redirect to the user's browser, but to show a web modal popup from the slack app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not supported. I know you don't want to do this but the only possible way to open a web page in web browser.